# How to find out UID of Active Directory user?

Tags: centos, domain-controller

I just want to verify that the output of:

```
id ad_user
```

is correct. On my rhel client I get uid=1234.

How can I verify that on the Windows Domain controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an AD attribute, [`uidNumber`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-uidnumber).

For example, with PowerShell:

```powershell
Get-ADUser john.doe -Properties * | select SamAccountName,uidNumber
```

Of course you can also just use the UI.